# Laravel Datatables Sorting Appended Fields

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datatables, eloquent

My Model `Items` is related to `Rooms`, which is related to `Buildings`, which is related to `Locations`.

Short: `Items` belongsTo `Rooms` belongsTo `Buildings` belongsTo `Locations`

At the index function of the `ItemController` I want to show a table of `Items`. I use Laravel Datatables. It works for 'simple' tables, but I ran into the problem of sorting/searching custom/appended fields, because they are not in the table of course.

Basically I want to join the `Room`, `Building` and `Location` Name for each `Item` in the displaying table.

This is my `Items` Model:

```
protected $appends = [
    'building_title',
    'location_title',
    'room_title',
];

public function getLocationTitleAttribute() {
    return $this->room->building->location->title;
}

public function getBuildingTitleAttribute() {
    return $this->room->building->title;
}

public function getRoomTitleAttribute() {
    return $this->room->title;
}
```

This is my Controller:

```
public function anyData()
{
    return Datatables::of(Item::query())->make(true);
}
```

What is the best approach to enable sorting/filtering for appended fields?
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution (no appended fields were used):

```
public function anyData()
{
    $items = Item::join('rooms', 'items.room_id', '=', 'rooms.id')
        ->join('buildings', 'rooms.building_id', '=', 'buildings.id')
        ->join('locations', 'buildings.location_id', '=', 'locations.id')
        ->select([
            'items.id',
            'items.title',
            'items.label_number',
            'items.fibu_number',
            'rooms.title as room_title',
            'buildings.title as building_title',
            'locations.title as location_title'
        ]);
    return Datatables::of($items)->make(true);
}
```